# Is new ObservableCollection<object>(ObjEnumerable.ToList()) same as Foreach and add?

Tags: c#

Is there any performance difference between the following two snippets?

## 1

```
IEnumerable<object> enumerable = ...
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>(enumerable.ToList());
```

## 2

```
IEnumerable<object> enumerable = ...
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
foreach (object o in enumerable)
{
  observableCollection.Add(o);
}
```

Comment: Don't guess. Measure it.

Comment: The first one creates an additional `List<object>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a performance difference.  The second method will raise the `CollectionChanged` event for each item in the list.  First will not.

This might be ignored if you are not subscribing to the event between creating the collection and adding the items.

If `objOCollection` is assigned to the UI before adding the items, this could cause the UI to perform poorly while the items are being added, as it will have to refresh for each change.  Creating the collection in full (whether through the constructor or adding the items) then assigning it to the UI will avoid this.

If you are subscribing to the `CollectionChanged` event and looking to react to it for each item, you will not be able to do this with the first method.

Comment: Yes, I need to bind this to UI in WPF. That's why I am asking this.  The only way I can keep it binding to UI is to use method 2,  but then I wonder if there is any performance issues.  mhm, now I wonder how can I ignore `the CollectionChange` event until I finish adding all items....

Comment: I would recommend using the first method.  If the ObservableCollection is a property on your ViewModel, make sure you fire `PropertyChanged` for the property after assigning it.